# OP comments always relevant, at least on some sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I don't know if this has been asked before, but if it has, I couldn't find it.

Some of the sites on SE have a small but not that small community, and in some of such sites, we'd want to see what the OP has to say on a comment/answer. Academia and Workplace come to mind, where the answers are a kind of mass dialogue.

However, if there are a lot of comments, only the most voted(let's call them 'relevant') can be seen by a viewer, and the OP's comment, if present, also gets buried with other unvoted comments. That necessitates opening of all comment trains, and makes it cumbersome to 'skim' through the thread.

Could we make the OP comments always relevant? I know they're highlighted, but that doesn't solve the above problem.

If there are any problems, I'd like to know - OP comments have always been relatively few in all the answers I've read so far on SE.

Comment: No, this will just increase the confusion, in my opinion, especially for those already familiar with the system.

Comment: @everyone If you're going to downvote, post a reason. Otherwise, I think the point is quite clear already. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If the OP has said something in a comment that's relevant to those reading or answering the question, you should edit that information into their question (and then flag the comment as obsolete).

If not, it's no more important than any other comment.

(This answer applies to comments on the question, as well as to comments on answers or in response to other comments on answers.)

Comment: What about a comment to someone else's answer/comment(like this one I'm writing right now, but imagine it's riddled below 20 others)? OPs don't just comment to their own question, you know.

Comment: @cst1992 This answer applies to those comments as well. If they provide important information to those reading or answering the question, they should be edited into the question; if not, they're no more important than any other comment.

Comment: What about [this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61653/meeting-in-the-restaurant-with-a-senior-what-should-i-have-done) question I asked a while ago? I have comments on most posts, with different views and contexts. I wouldn't want to clutter the main question with those contexts.

Comment: @cst1992 which of those comments do you think needs to have priority? I don't see how the post would be improved in any way if any of your comments there were prioritized. I think the way comments are currently displayed does a good job of showing important details and critical comments, while hiding [unimportant comments](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61653/meeting-in-the-restaurant-with-a-senior-what-should-i-have-done#comment163589_61653)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of trying to bring comments by the asker/answerer to the fore, I think it would be far better to encourage them to use their question/answer to provide all their content of value.

Comment: Ideally yes, but I still see comments as-is.

Comment: @cst1992 By "comments as-is" are you perhaps talking about a discussion in comments that involves the asker/answerer - it is that which I think should be avoided.